# MySQL invalid result in correct query

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm creating a login system, but PHP print errors with invalid MySQL result.
Query is 100% correct, $_POST have a valid data.

```
 Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ..../public_html/libs/basic.php on line 27
```

Here is PHP:

```
        if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='". $login ."' AND `pass`='". createPasswordHash($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']) ."' LIMIT 1");             
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                $user_checked = 1;
                $token = md5(uniqid() . "salt" . rand());
                setUserConfig('token', $token);
                setUserConfig('token_time', time() + (60 * 60));
                return true;
            }
        }
```

createPasswordHash:

```
function createPasswordHash($login, $pass)
{
    return md5($login . "_". md5($pass));
}
```

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="?p=home">

Login: <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Wpisz login..." />
Hasło: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Wpisz hasło..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
</form>
```

Comment: What do you get if you do this: `var_dump($result);`? And what about `echo mysql_error();`. You are assuming that everything will work perfectly every single time. You need to *check for errors*. Every time an error can occur you should make sure it didn't.

Comment: Output: `bool(false)` This query works in phpMyAdmin. 

Connect with database - before login code
http://pastebin.com/YeZxqmaC

Comment: @Maku123PL `bool(false)` means that your query has failed. `mysql_query()` expects **two** parameters like so: `mysql_query("your query", $connection);` where `$connection` is the resource of your mysql connection

Comment: @Maku123PL does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652806/mysql-invalid-result-in-correct-query/29654146#29654146) answer your question? I'm curious

Answer (score 0):

`bool(false)` means that your query has failed.

If your query is correct then the error is in `mysql_query()` which expects **two** parameters like so:

```
mysql_query("your query", $connection) OR die(mysql_error());
```

where `$connection` is the resource of your mysql connection:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");
```

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> If the link identifier (*`$connection`*) is not specified, the last link opened by [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an **E_WARNING** level error is generated.

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to `fetch` your result with `[mysql_fetch_row][1]` (or something equivalent) like :

```
...
$result = mysql_fetch_row ( $result );
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

You can also try this to see what is in your `$result` :

```
print_r ($result);
```

or

```
var_dump ($result);
```

Just a warning, mysql is deprecated. It's recommended to use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)